# Spring Framework Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
public GetChannelAccountRes getAccounts(GetChannelAccountReq request) {
        LawAccountEntity account = new LawAccountEntity();
        if(request.getTransactionCode().equals("yyyyyyy") && "1".equals(account.getAccountOwnerType())) {
           UserParameter userParameter = userParameterRepository.findByGroupKeyAndKey("xxxxxxx","11111111");
           
           
            }  
        return remoteChannelAccountInquiryService.getAccounts(request);
    }
```

Hi, I have this code block. How can I add this userParameter value in request. I want to return something in if statement `userParameter` value and `remoteChannelAccountInquiryService.getAccounts(request)` value together.

Comment: add a new method in your InquiryService that takes both request and userParameter...and the method should also return GetChannelAccountRes  type.

Answer (score 0):

Java, as a language, doesn't allow multiple return types, i.e. returning two values from the same method. If you want/have to return multiple things from the same method, you'll need to change your return type. The simplest would be to return a Map, i.e.

```
public Map<GetChannelAccountRes,UserParameter>getAccounts(GetChannelAccountReq request) {
    Map<GetChannelAccountRes,UserParameter> map = new HashMap<>();
    if (your condition) {
      map.put(account, userParameter);
    } else {
      map.put(account, null);  // or some other default value for userParameter
    }
    return map;
}
```

but then the caller would either have to iterate the map key/values, or know the key (i.e. the account)

Honestly, the better solution using Java would be to perform the if statement logic in its own method that returns UserParameter and then add the UserParameter as an optional argument to your existing method so that you're always only returning one object.

```
public UserParameter getUserParameter(GetChannelAccountReq request) {
  UserParameter userParameter = null;  // or some other default value
  if(request.getTransactionCode().equals("yyyyyyy") && 
    userParameter = "1".equals(account.getAccountOwnerType())) {
      userParameterRepository.findByGroupKeyAndKey("xxxxxxx","11111111");
    }  
  return userParameter;
}

public GetChannelAccountRes getAccounts(GetChannelAccountReq request, UserParameter... userParameter) {
    if (userParameter[0] != null) {
      // whatever logic that requires both request and userParameter goes here
    }
    return getChannelAccountRes
  }
```

If the same caller calls both getUserParameter and getAccount, then it would have both objects, which is what I think you intend when you say you wanted both returned together.  The varargs (...) parameter in `getAccounts` is a stylistic matter of taste, and is an array, which is why we check the first index for null. You can do the same thing without using var args like so.

```
public GetChannelAccountRes getAccounts(GetChannelAccountReq request) {
  return getAccounts(request, null); // or some default value for UserParameter intstead of null
}
public GetChannelAccountRes getAccounts(GetChannelAccountReq request, UserParameter... userParameter) { 
    if (userParameter != null) {
      // whatever logic that requires both request and userParameter goes here
    }
    return getChannelAccountRes
```